# Python Selenium MySQL - Insert if the ID does not exists

Tags: python, mysql, selenium, sql-update

I have this code:

```
def read_excel_all_members(mycursor, mydb):
with open('.\\docs\\allMembers.csv') as allMembersCSV:
    csv_reader_object = csv.reader(allMembersCSV, delimiter=';')
    next(csv_reader_object)
    sql = "INSERT INTO allMembers (idnr, lastname, firstname) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    for row in csv_reader_object:
        sql2 = 'SELECT count(*) FROM allMembers WHERE idnr =' + row[0]
        exists = mycursor.execute(sql2)
        if not exists != 0:
            val = [
                (row[0], row[1], row[2])
            ]
            mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
mydb.commit()
```

But i always get an error - I just want to insert the row if the row[0] doesn´t exists at that moment?

What´s wrong in my Code?

Error:

````
  File "C:/Users/usera/PycharmProjects/untitled1/console.py", line 38, in <module>
    functions.read_excel_all_members(mycursor, mydb)
  File "C:\Users\usera\PycharmProjects\untitled1\functions.py", line 128, in read_excel_all_members
    exists = mycursor.execute(sql2)
  File "C:\Users\usera\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 521, in execute
    self._connection.handle_unread_result()
  File "C:\Users\usera\PycharmProjects\untitled1\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 1059, in handle_unread_result
    raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found``` 


Pls help me.

The CSV is like:

> ID;Familienname;Vorname
1538;Jakob;Schwarz
````

Answer (score 0):

Now I have the solution:

```
def read_excel_all_members(mycursor, mydb):
with open('.\\docs\\allMembers.csv') as allMembersCSV:
    csv_reader_object = csv.reader(allMembersCSV, delimiter=';')
    next(csv_reader_object)
    sql = 'INSERT INTO allMembers (idnr, lastname, firstname) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
    for row in csv_reader_object:
        sql2 = 'SELECT count(*) FROM allMembers WHERE idnr =' + row[0]
        mycursor.execute(sql2)
        result = mycursor.fetchone()
        if result == (0,):
            val = [
                (row[0], row[1], row[2])
            ]
            mycursor.execute(sql, val[0])
mydb.commit()
```